# Query InfluxDB with CASE or IF statement?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, influxql, chronograf

I am gathering metrics from my philips hue bridge and putting them into an InfluxDB. I'd like to be able to display some of these metrics on a dashboard.

A basic query looks like this:

```
SELECT mean("state.bri") AS "mean_state.bri" FROM "telegraf_hue"."autogen"."hue" WHERE time > :dashboardTime: AND "lamp"='Couch' GROUP BY time(:interval:) FILL(null)
```

This returns a nice graph that shows the brightness level of the light.

[Basic Query Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA5z5.png)

The problem with this query is that the light isn't actually on all of that time. The Hue Bridge returns the last brightness level, even if it's off.

I can see if it is on by checking `"state.on"` for a `true` or `false` value.

```
SELECT mean("state.bri") AS "mean_state.bri" FROM "telegraf_hue"."autogen"."hue" WHERE "state.on" = true AND time > :dashboardTime: AND "lamp"='Couch' GROUP BY time(:interval:) FILL(null)
```

This only returns points where the light is on.

[Query where light is on results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UTtw.png)

What I'd like to do something like a `CASE` statement like in MySQL:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN "state.on" = true THEN mean("state.bri") ELSE 0 END FROM "telegraf_hue"."autogen"."hue" WHERE time > :dashboardTime: AND "lamp"='Couch' GROUP BY time(:interval:) FILL(null)
```

This doesn't work. It fails with:

```
Request failed with status code 400
```

How can I accomplish something similar with InfluxDB? Ultimately, I'll be building the dashboards in Grafana, if that matters.

Comment: There are no mysql's `case` or `if` equivalents in influxql. What's wrong with your second variant? It shows what you want: no light <-> no data on graph. If you really need zero datapoints on graph for state.on=false you'll have to use `select ...  from (select ...) ...` syntax with fill(0) in outer query.